# Convert CSV to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dictionary

```
data = {'': '11', 'RecID': '11', 'year': '2020', 'Flugnummer': 'DL67', 'cabin_class': 'economy', 'DEPARTURE_AIRPORT': 'ZRH', 'ARRIVAL_AIRPORT': 'ATL', 'Anzahl Flugsegmente': '1', 'distance': '7652', 'currencies': 'USD', 'EMISSIONS_KGCO2EQ': '1260', 'dep_country': 'CH', 'dep_coordinates': 'c(8.548056', 'arr_country': ' 47.458056)', 'arr_coordinates': 'US', None: ['c(-84.428101', ' 33.6367)']}  

print("Payload ")
def emissions(data):  
    test_dic = {} # New dictionary
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        if data["DEPARTURE_AIRPORT"][i] == "DEPARTURE_AIRPORT":
            return DEPARTURE_AIRPORT
        if data["ARRIVAL_AIRPORT"][i] == "ARRIVAL_AIRPORT":
            return ARRIVAL_AIRPORT
        if data["cabin_class"][i] == "cabin_class":
            return cabin_class
        test_dic.update({"segments": [{ "origin": DEPARTURE_AIRPORT, "destination": ARRIVAL_AIRPORT},], "cabin_class": cabin_class, "currencies":["USD"]})
    return payload
print(emissions(data))
```

Desired format: data = {"segments" : [{"origin" : "ZRH","destination" : "ATL"},],"cabin_class" : "economy","currencies" : ["USD"]}

I have this dataset above `data` which should be transformed into the desired format below. I tried the function above which I wrote, but it seems not to work, and whith the codes already online I couldn't figure it out. Excuse me, if I ask this question again. But I can not get it to work, to change the list/csv into the dictionary.

Comment: How is the destination for `LAX` airport `ZRH`? Shouldn't it be `ACC`?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Sorry you are right, typo

Comment: shouldn't it be  `["economy"]` instead of `"economy"`?

Comment: @Hatatister No, the format must be like in the desired format due to the API input

Comment: So ["economy", "business"] would be bad input data? Or is your desired output a list of dictionaries [{"segments" ...}, {"segments"}]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict` and `zip(*)` are you're friends for this task

```
from collections import defaultdict


def emissions(data):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for org, arr, cls, cur in zip(*data.values()):
        result["segments"].append({
                "origin": org,
                "destionation": arr})
        result["cabin_class"].append(cls)
        result["currencies"].append(cur)
    return dict(result)
```

Explanation:

defaultdict takes a type. If a key is not present in the dict, yet, then it will generate a new value of the given type, insert into the value under the given key and then return the value. Otherwise it just returns the value associated with the given key.

zip(*) is kind of a matrix transpose operation. It switches columnss to rows. Columns are all the values of your given dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would this also work when using a .csv as input in some way?

Comment: Sure. Have a look on https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader . You have to modify the for line to roughly `for org, arr, cls, cur in reader`. CSV reader returns an iterator over rows (data.values() is returning an iterator over columns). So no transformation is needed.

Comment: And how would it work then with the data input updated above? Sorry to bother you again, and thank you for your help!

Comment: Which input do you mean? From CSV file? Or your original data from your question?

Comment: The problem got solved, thank you very much!